# user input name times age

Tags: java, for-loop

so I need to make the following:
when a user types their name in the console then gets prompted for filling in their age, after that it needs to display the name the amount if times their age is. So for example
User input is Mikey
age input is: 4
then console prints:
Mikey
Mikey
Mikey
Mikey

So far I made the following code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String invoer;
        String invoer2;
        System.out.print("Fill in your name:");
        invoer = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Fill in your age:");
        invoer2 = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("" + invoer);
        System.out.print(" " + invoer2);
    }
```

I'm very new to java so I'm not sure what the problem is nor what the fix could be. I have been searching for such code to see what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to find any.

Comment: What is your output atm?

Comment: Fill in your name:Mikey
Fill in your age:18
Mikey 18BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String invoer;
    String invoer2;
    System.out.print("Fill in your name:");
    invoer = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Fill in your age:");
    invoer2 = br.readLine();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(invoer2); i++) {
            System.out.println(invoer);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Age should be a number");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print("" + invoer);
    System.out.print(" " + invoer2);
}
```

You have get number from user's input. This can be done with `Integer.parseInt(invoer2)`. However it can throw `NumberFormatException` if the input isn't a valid number.

However I would recommend using `Scanner`.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String invoer;
    String invoer2;
    System.out.print("Fill in your name:");
    invoer = s.next();
    System.out.print("Fill in your age:");
    try {
        invoer2 = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < invoer2; i++) {
            System.out.println(invoer);
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("It wasn't valid age");
    }
    System.out.print("" + invoer);
    System.out.print(" " + invoer2);
}
```

Comment: You might want to add the part that he needs a for loop in the end to do the repeated printing (although I would not put that code into the answer; let him do the work)

Comment: @Artifacialic you can accept it by clicking on a gray tick below the answer score.

Comment: @GhostCat I added a solution with a `Scanner` which I would prefer. Let the OP do the rest.

Comment: @Xenteros I know but it said I should wait.

Comment: @Artifacialic I've changed the `print` to `println` as it's what you wanted to achieve

Comment: @Artifacialic I think the wait time is over.

Comment: @xenteros Ye I'm at school and I had to go to a different class, I accepted it as a solution! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop for printing the name once for each year of age.  But first, convert the string input for age into an `int` which can then be used as a boundary for the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String invoer;
    int invoer2;
    System.out.print("Fill in your name:");
    invoer = br.readLine();
    System.out.print("Fill in your age:");
    invoer2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    for (int i=0; i < invoer2; ++i) {
        System.out.print(invoer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no reason why this should be downvoted.  Explanation?

Comment: I don't see no reason either. It's correct and working

Comment: I didnt downvote, but: i guess your code ignores the number formatting issues.

Comment: Practically speaking, just catching the number format exception itself is useless, unless the program attempts to recover by asking for another input.  _None_ of the answers given do this.  There is nothing wrong with the program rolling over if a bad age is entered.